# Tasks are getting failed

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, futuretask

```
Task failed at: 2016-04-10T13:03:44.152+07:00
com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.TaskComponentException:
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.bulkexternalstagedataload.BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.runTask(BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.java:489)
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.AbstractTaskComponent.runTaskWrapper(AbstractTaskComponent.java:434)
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.AbstractTaskComponent.run(AbstractTaskComponent.java:299)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.TaskComponentException: Load failed for 271 files to datasource rai4usg2 and table inst4_usg2..u_in_recharge with usp_id 14, database part key 12, database subpart key 1
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.bulkexternalstagedataload.BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.executeAndGetAllResults(BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.java:572)
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.bulkexternalstagedataload.BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.runTask(BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.java:463)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.TaskComponentException: Load failed for 271 files to datasource rai4usg2 and table inst4_usg2..u_in_recharge with usp_id 14, database part key 12, database subpart key 1
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.bulkexternalstagedataload.BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask$BulkExternalStageDataLoadThread.call(BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.java:1059)
        at com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.bulkexternalstagedataload.BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask$BulkExternalStageDataLoadThread.call(BulkExternalStageDataLoadTask.java:769)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        ... 1 more
```

Does anybody have any idea why i am getting this error?

Comment: This looks suspicious: "inst4_usg2..u_in_recharge".  Isn't the syntax "database.tablename"?  What is that extra "." doing there?

Comment: Thats a log only ,we are printing like that and in backend we adhere the correct naming convention .